# Unable to update software centre from terminal

Tags: software-center

Unable to update software centre via terminal and update software via centre is very slow and not able to download software from centre.
Please help.

```
vineshnair@vineshnair-Lenovo-G580:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-software packagekit
[sudo] password for vineshnair: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score 1):

From the message shown to you, it seems you have another tool running with elevated privileges. Close any instances of Software Center or Synaptic Manager and try again.